# Why is my Prisma ORM Client building on Windows and not Mac?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, package.json, prisma

We have an Electron desktop app using prisma on top of a local SQLite database. Our Prisma build on Mac isn't working. Our windows distribution builds as expected, and is fully functional as a standalone desktop app.

Also frustrating - running our Mac app in our dev environment works fine.

We have tried a significant number of configuration changes in our package.json and prisma schema.

The client errors revolve around missing fields on the response objects, suggesting our Prisma usage on our server just isn't returning any data or is otherwise erroring out. Because this is a production build of this desktop app we can't see the server logs.

We expect that the issue lay in our package.json build config, or our prisma schema config. Both pasted below for reference.

Prisma schema configs (leaving out the database schema; we know these are working because our dev build is working as expected)

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output = "../node_modules/.prisma/client"
  previewFeatures = ["napi"]
  binaryTargets = ["native", "windows", "darwin", "darwin-arm64"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:nimbleStore2.db"
}
```

Package.json build

```
"build": {
    "productName": "NimbleAB",
    "appId": "com.Nimble|electron.NimbleAB",
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources"
    },
    "asar": true,
    "asarUnpack": "**/query-engine-windows.exe",
    "files": [
      "app/dist/**/*",
      "app/electron/**/*"
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "rpm",
        "snap",
        "AppImage"
      ]
    },
    "extraResources": [
      "prisma/nimblestore2.db",
      "node_modules/.prisma/**/*",
      "node_modules/@prisma/client/**/*"
    ]
  },
```